# mixing automatic abbrev expansions with explicit-only expansions?

Tags: abbrev

**Q:** can I mix abbrev expansions such that some expand automatically, and some only with an explicit call?

When `abbrev-mode` is enabled, an abbrev expands whenever typing a self-inserting whitespace or punctuation character.  However, `expand-abbrev` will expand the abbrev at point *even when `abbrev-mode` is disabled*.

Is it possible to enable `abbrev-mode` and have some expansions happen automatically (ie, after whitespace and punctuation), but others expand *only* when I explicitly call `expand-abbrev`?

Rationale:

- I'd like to use abbrevs automatically to correct common mistyped words (eg, `teh` => `the`)...
- ... but would like to have explicit control of others that I use for shorthand (eg, sometimes I want to leave `dem` as `dem`, and other times I'd like it to expand to `democracy`).

  - (I know I could type `dem C-q <space>`, but it's awkward to do so and I usually want to use the shorthand rather than the expansion.)

To forestall well-intentioned "why not use `yasnippet`?" inquiries:

- I'm experimenting with a combination of `abbrev-mode` and `yasnippet`, and would prefer to use the latter for complicated expansions and the former for simple ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`define-abbrev` accepts a predicate, just use it to specify the abbrev should only expand when requested explicitly.

```
(define-abbrev text-mode-abbrev-table "dem" "democracy" nil
  :enable-function (lambda () (eq this-command 'expand-abbrev)))
```

The above abbrev will not expand when you hit `SPC` (or any other self-inserting character), but it will expand when you invoke `expand-abbrev` directly.

You'll probably want to bind it to a key then:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-i") #'expand-abbrev)
```

Comment: Thanks -- I'm trying to define one table with explicit-only expansions (via `define-abbrev-table`) to be included as a parent for the core table (or perhaps it should be the other way around).  Not working yet, but I presume that some variant of this answer will work in `define-abbrev-table` as well.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, see [abel](https://github.com/abo-abo/abel).
Here's the predicate:

```
(defun abel-p ()
  "Don't expand in strings, comments and function arguments."
  (let ((ppss (syntax-ppss)))
    (unless (or (elt ppss 3) (elt ppss 4))
      (or (memq this-command '(expand-abbrev aya-open-line))
          (save-match-data
            (and (looking-back "([[:alnum:]]*")
                 (save-excursion
                   (goto-char (match-beginning 0))
                   (and (not (looking-back "(lambda *"))
                        (condition-case nil
                            (progn
                              (up-list)
                              (backward-sexp)
                              (not
                               (or
                                (looking-at "(defun *")
                                (looking-back "(let\\*? *"))))
                          (error t))))))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Would introduce an own mode for that:

my-special-mode, once called, whould create an

my-special-mode-abbrev-table.

Than create a command which combines toggling resp. switching-on with expand-abbrev.