# abbrev table inherit properties from other tables?

Tags: abbrev

**Q:** how can I get abbrev tables to inherit properties?

*Motivation*: I'd like to mix and match abbrevs such that some expand automatically when typing, while others expand only when I explicitly tell them to via `expand-abbrev`.  (See [a previous question on this issue](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/8267/mixing-automatic-abbrev-expansions-with-explicit-only-expansions).)

*Solution in a simple case*: cribbing from the accepted answer on the above question, one can define a single abbrev to expand explicitly with:

```
(define-abbrev text-mode-abbrev-table "abbrev" "expansion value" nil
  :enable-function (lambda () (eq this-command 'expand-abbrev)))
```

*Problem*: I've got a whole bunch of abbrevs I'd like to use, so doing the above for each one would be tedious.  It *should* be possible to use `define-abbrev-table` to automate everything, and then have the actual abbrev tables inherit from them.  So, consider the following two tables:

```
(define-abbrev-table 'automatic-table
  '(("test1" "This should expand automatically")
    ;; ... more abbrevs here
    ("test2" "This should also expand automatically")))

(define-abbrev-table 'explicit-table
  '(("test3" "This should expand only after expand-abbrev")
    ;; ... more abbrevs here
    ("test4" "This should also expand only after expand-abbrev"))
  :enable-function (lambda () (eq this-command 'expand-abbrev)))
```

It seems like it should then be possible to do the following:

```
(define-abbrev-table 'text-mode-abbrev-table nil
  "Table's docstring"
  :parents (list explicit-table automatic-table))
```

It does not quite work out, however.  `text-mode-abbrev-table` correctly inherits the abbrevs defined in `automatic-table` and `explicit-table`, but they always fire automatically when typing.  In other words, the `:enable-function` property on `explicit-table` gets ignored.

*How can I ensure that the `:enable-function` property gets inherited for the abbrevs in the relevant table without being applied to abbrevs in a different table?*

Comment: Hmmm, as the implementor of those :parents and :enable-function thingies, I'd expect your code to work, so either there's some "subtle" detail that I'm missing or you're hitting a bug.  I suggest you `M-x report-emacs-bug` with a concrete test case.

Comment: @Dan could you figure it out? Otherwise you might want to delete this.

Comment: works for me, with or without the doctring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ha!  There's a subtle bug in your code: the 3rd argument of `define-abbrev-table` is the *docstring*, so it treats `:enable-function` as the docstring and the subsequent function as a property name (with missing value).

Comment: I've just pushed a fix for that problem in Emacs's "master" branch.

Comment: Thanks for the additional thought on this, although I'm still getting the same behavior even when I use a placeholder for the docstring (tested with `emacs -Q`).  Any chance you could edit your answer to show the code that actually does work in case I've missed something?

Comment: I just added `"Docstring."` before `:enable-function` and tested it with `emacs24 -Q` and it worked (i.e. after enabling text-mode and abbrev-mode, `test1 SPC` expands while `test3 SPC` doesn't).

Comment: I'm flabbergasted.  I did exactly that and `test3 SPC` still expands.  I cannot figure out what I've missed, so will keep trying.